# MPAndroidChart Custom Marker View in Kotlin

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am porting my app to android and was using the iOS version of this library, so I am not too familiar with Android development.

I was trying to implement this class [XYMARKER](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/custom/XYMarkerView.java) to then make it like how it was on my iOS app. But I am having issues with creating the custom class, here is what I have:

```
class XYMarkerView(context: Context, xAxisValueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter): MarkerView(context, R.layout.marker_view) {

    var tvContent: TextView
    var xAxisValueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter
    var format: DecimalFormat

    init{
        this.xAxisValueFormatter = xAxisValueFormatter
        tvContent = findViewById(R.id.tvContent)
        format = DecimalFormat("###.0")
    }

//    fun XYMarkerView(context: Context , xAxisValueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter) {
//
//
//        this.xAxisValueFormatter = xAxisValueFormatter
//        tvContent = findViewById(R.id.tvContent)
//        format = DecimalFormat("###.0")
//    }

    // callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
    // content (user-interface)
    override fun refreshContent(e: Entry, highlight: Highlight) {

        tvContent.text = "x: " + xAxisValueFormatter.getFormattedValue(e.x, null) + ", y: " + format.format(e.y)

        super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
    }

    override fun getOffset(): MPPointF {
        return MPPointF(-(width / 2).toFloat(), -height.toFloat())
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I have been messing around with this for a while and can't seem to make it work. Right now when I tap on a point I get the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.eic.graphtest.app, PID: 24549
>                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter axis